# Projectile Physics mechanic broken java

Tags: java, eclipse, physics, projectile

For my game to become engaging I want the enemy to fire bullets at the mothership and the player. However I am running errors whenever I uncomment out the physics mechanics that I wrote in each class. 
Here is the one for the player as example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < game.eb.size(); i++)
        {
            EntityB tempEnt = game.eb.get(i);

            if(Physics.Collision(this, tempEnt)) {
                c.removeEntity(tempEnt);
                Game.HEALTH -= 20;
                game.setEnemy_killed(game.getEnemy_killed() + 1);
            }
        }
```

So I used a method that defines essentially the 'good' and the 'bad' through EntityA and EntityB. So when the Player shoots at an Enemy, the Enemy will disappear. However when the Player is shot by an Enemy, the player loses health. I deduct 20 health from the point out of 100 so that the game is more intense. 
Here is the mothership's mechanic:

```
for(int i = 0; i < game.eb.size(); i++)
        {
            EntityB tempEnt = game.eb.get(i);

            if(Physics.Collision(this, tempEnt)) {
                c.removeEntity(tempEnt);
                Game.MHEALTH -= 20;
                game.setEnemy_killed(game.getEnemy_killed() + 1);
            }
        }
```

I will post a new version of the game through the dropbox link. The physics mechanics are commented out so that the game is in a playable state. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mm5u370yp8t1twp/AAAGMHveVu1rps4qqX5C6GVfa?dl=0

Comment: Unrelated (probably): making health a global variable is a *very* bad idea...

Comment: Ok so make it local?

Comment: Not local but a property of the player / enemy classes; again this is just a small code style suggestion and probably not the source of your actual issue

Comment: Ok I will have a look tonight

Comment: Didn't get around to looking at it but just in case I get stuck where should I put health in the classes?

Comment: As long as health is a property of the *player* and not the game itself, you can implement it however you like.

Comment: Alright I'll work on that.

Comment: So I didn't change anything in Game.java (main game loop) but I reassigned Health and MHealth to Player and Mothership respectively. By doing Player.Health and Mothership.MHealth.

Comment: It says my errors are happening is coming from p.tick() and c.tick() and tick();

Comment: @meowgoesthedog